# "Too many tables" error on querying base class object in Hibernate/JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

My class model is in the following way.
There is one Base class called "IdClass" which has id, version, createdBy, createdDate, etc information.
All other entity classes derive from this base class (and hence get the IdClass attributes like id, version, etc automatically).

I use Hibernate/JPA to handle the db level implementation of these classes.

I added another class called Attachment which contains a blob to store any attachment. To keep it generic, I added a reference to the IdClass in the Attachment. This way, any entity can have one or more attachments without having the overhead of having to store blobs in every table.

The problem is when I try to insert an Attachment object. I need to add the reference to the entity specified. I have a common service method "createAttachment" that takes an attachment object and the 'id' for the entity. Now, in this method, I need to find the entity using this 'id' and then associate that with the new Attachment object. To do this, I have written the following method "findEntity"

```
public IdClass findEntity(Long id) {

    IdClass entity;
    entity = (IdClass) getSession().get(IdCass.class, id);
    return entity;
}
```

But when this method gets executed, I get an exception saying "Too many tables: MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join". 
I have more than 100 entities. Hibernate/JPA. It looks like Hibernate/JPA is trying to do a join on all the sub-classes of the IdClass, when just querying on the IdClass table itself is sufficient (as the id is stored in the IdClass table).

Also, I have tried creating Hibernate Criteria queries to search for the entities. Even that results in the same Too many tables error.

Please let me know what is it that I am doing wrong. How can I fetch the IdClass object using just the id (without having to incur joins on all the sub-class tables)?

Comment: Do you use `@MappedSuperclass`? Please show code for `IdClass` and `Attachment`

Comment: @orid , I am not using `@MappedSuperClass` annotation. The InheritanceType strategy used is "Joined". Here is the code for [IDClass.java](http://pastebin.com/DhU6XBh5) and here is the code for [Attachment.java](http://pastebin.com/pLegA1jn)

Comment: @OriDar Hey, I ran into the same issue. I am using MappedSuperClass at very high level, and for further hierarchy I am also using @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) for some of my entities.

Please share your thoughts. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most concise solution, but I was able to work around the same issue by using a `NamedQuery`:

```
@NamedQuery(name="BaseItem.findById", 
            query="SELECT a FROM BaseItem a WHERE a.id = :id")
```

And then I have the following utility-function for invoking the query (using pure JPA):

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends BaseItem> T findById(Class<T> entityClass, long id, 
                                                  EntityManager em) {
        try {
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery("BaseItem.findById");
            query.setParameter("id", id);

            T result = (T)query.getSingleResult();
            return result;
        }
        catch (NoResultException ignored) {
            //expected
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.warn("Failed to execute 'findByAndId' query for id=" + id, e);
        }

        //couldn't find it
        return null;
    }
```

And to use it to lookup an arbitrary entity through the superclass by id, I call:

```
BaseItemDAO.findById(BaseItem.class, id, em);
```

And then JPA/Hibernate does its magic behind the scenes to ensure that what gets returned is the complete subclass entity for the provided id, as opposed to just the superclass fields.  And it does so without dying with the 'too many tables' error.